# Adding the NOT_NULL constraint to an SQL column

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to add the NOT_NULL constraint to a column in an SQL h2 database, using

```
ALTER TABLE CHARACTERS ADD CONSTRAINT nn_PID NOT_NULL (PLAYER_ID);
```

This follows the pattern I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp):

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)
```

Except I change the constraint, table and column names. But I get this error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE CHARACTERS ADD CONSTRAINT NN_PID NOT_NULL[*] (PLAYER_ID) "; expected "., COMMENT, PRIMARY, INDEX, KEY, CHECK, UNIQUE, FOREIGN"; SQL statement:
>   ALTER TABLE CHARACTERS ADD CONSTRAINT nn_PID NOT_NULL (PLAYER_ID) [42001-168] 42001/42001 (Help)

How can I add the NOT_NULL constraint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [H2 SQL Grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html):

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN NAME SET NOT NULL;
```

So we can use:

```
ALTER TABLE CHARACTERS ALTER PLAYER_ID SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Just a question: According with H2 grammar...

        ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN NAME NULL;

is also valid. it does not have any effect. Do you know why?