# Having issues while running select query on h2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I am running a sample query on H2 database as explained below -

```
select count(*) from Employee where employee_name is not null;
```

But the issue is H2 is not supporting `is not null`, please suggest what could be the alternative for this.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672498/adding-the-not-null-constraint-to-an-sql-column

Comment: H2 absolutely supports `is not null`. What exactly is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
select count(*) from Employee 

WHERE employee_name = ? or (employee_name is null and ? is null);
```

Expression employee_name IS NULL returns TRUE if variable employee_name has the value NULL, 
otherwise it returns FALSE.